Designing Models that are open for extension but closed for modification
Let's say I have some model code like the following with quite a few references in a moderately sized existing system:
public class House
{
    public House(IEnumerable<Window> windows)
    {
        Windows = windows;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Window> Windows { get; private set; }


}

public class Window
{
    public Window(string brand, int height, int width)
    {
        Brand = brand;
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
    }

    public string Brand { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }
}

A new requirement comes along.  Parts of the system need to know if a particular Window is SolarResistant, however other parts don't care and may not know if a window is solar resistant.
We could extend our window class to represent the possibility of the window being solar resistant
public class WindowMaybeSolarResistant : Window
{
    public WindowMaybeSolarResistant(string brand, int height, int width, bool isSolarResistant) : base(brand, height, width)
    {
        IsSolarResistant = isSolarResistant;
    }

    public bool IsSolarResistant { get; private set; }
}

My problem is what to do about House?  The system is fairly coupled to the idea that a House has Windows.
We could just add another constructor to window instead
public class Window : IWindow
{
    public Window(string brand, int height, int width)
    {
        Brand = brand;
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
        IsSolarResistant = false;  //What if this is really true for the window though?  Could someone use the wrong constructor?
    }

    public Window(string brand, int height, int width, bool isSolarResistant)
    {
        Brand = brand;
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
        IsSolarResistant = isSolarResistant;
    }

    public string Brand { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSolarResistant { get; private set; }
}

The house could use generics instead?  This guarantees that a window has certain properties, but leaves room for expansion.
public interface IWindow
{ 
    public string Brand { get;  }
    public int Height { get;  }
    public int Width { get;  }
}


public class House<TWindow> where TWindow : IWindow
{
    public House(IEnumerable<TWindow> windows)
    {
        Windows = windows;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TWindow> Windows { get; private set; }

}

You extend House, but this seems like it could get out of control?
public class HouseCouldHaveSolarWindows : House
{
    public HouseCouldHaveSolarWindows(IEnumerable<WindowMaybeSolarResistant> windows) : base(windows)
    {
    }

    public new IEnumerable<WindowMaybeSolarResistant> Windows { get; private set; }
}

I hope my puzzling above makes sense.  I am trying to figure out the best way to extend a class that is coupled to another class when additional properties come along that some subsections of a system require.
I'm trying to find a way to follow the Open/Closed principle with the models, so that my models are open for extension (new properties) and closed for modification.

Is there a typo in the title? The actual question is about designing models that are closed for modification, correct?

The way you've described it, I would just attach a "property bag" to each major component, and put in the relevant properties based on stocked item or ordered item. And have a "master property list" of: SolarResistent; OneWay; Tinted; Shipping1; Shipping2; etc. Allows you to query: "where property bag contains ..." Reporting just means listing the contents of the bag; with maybe a lookup for an extended desc or pricing component.

Personally I would go with another approach - adding some "feature" collection to the window class. Something along these lines (not tested, just to give an idea):
public interface IWindowFeature;

public class SolarResistantWindowFeature : IWindowFeature
{
    // some SolarResistantFeature props 
}

public class Window
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> Features = new();
    
    // ...

    public void SetFeature<T>(T feature) where T : class, IWindowFeature 
      => Features[typeof(T)] = feature;

    public T? GetFeature<T>() where T : class, IWindowFeature
      => Features.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var v)
          ? v as T 
          : null;
}

And then set/get features when needed:
window.SetFeature(new SolarResistantWindowFeature());
var hasSolarResistance = window.GetFeature<SolarResistantWindowFeature>() is not null;

Which will allow to have as many features as needed (and extending number of them without modifying the existing types) querying them when needed and you will not need to create a separate class for all relevant combination of features.

There's a common misunderstanding that a class like the Window is object-oriented. It isn't really. Usually, object-oriented design implies data with behaviour, and the Window class has no behaviour.
Part of description of the open/closed principle (OCP) is that classes are

open for extension. This means that the behavior of the module can be extended. As the requirements of the application change, we can extend the module with new behaviors that satisfy those changes. In other words, we are able to change what the module does.
- APPP, Robert C. Martin, Prentice Hall, 2006, ch. 9, my emphasis

Notice that the description of the OCP is focused on how objects behave, rather than the shape that they have. The APPP examples further illustrates this with an example that involves drawing shapes on a canvas, where the solution turns out to be a virtual Draw method that classes can override.
You can only follow or implement the OCP when you know what the application code (here e.g. House) wants to do with a Window. We can't see that in the OP, so it's hard to suggest a solution.

All that said, the simplest way forward may just be to add IsSolarResistant to Window:
public class Window
{
    public Window(string brand, int height, int width)
        this(brand, height, width, false)
    {
    }

    public Window(string brand, int height, int width, bool isSolarResistant)
    {
        Brand = brand;
        Height = height;
        Width = width;
        IsSolarResistant = isSolarResistant;
    }

    public string Brand { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSolarResistant { get; private set; }
}

This, at least, is a non-breaking change, but you'd be violating the OCP in the sense that you'll now need to go and modify House to make use of the new property. As far as I can see, however, you'd need to do that for all the suggested solutions, including the answer from Guru Stron.

The question of how not to violate The Open Closed Principle is answered by The Dependency Inversion Principle (it seems to me the most clear):

Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.

This means you need to define an interface - Window and then dependencies in your consumers should be directed to this interface, and not to specific classes (NormalWindow, SolarResistantWindow, etc.).
P.S. You don't really have objects, you have data structures without behavior. I encourage you to think about what useful behavior your objects could have. I have windows at home, and they have sizes, shapes, and someone made them, but their work is to let light in while protecting the inside of the house from cold, rain, etc.

From what I understand either solution requires some refactoring.
At this stage, maybe the introduction of an abstraction for window attributes could be worth it.
A Window might not just be solar resistant but also insulated or more in the future, and instead of having to keep adding true/false properties one could keep adding abstracted window attributes without further upgrading the classes in the future.
The Window class could be updated to support the attributes:
public class Window
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IWindowAttribute> _windowAttributes;

    public Window(string brand, int height, int width, IEnumerable<IWindowAttribute> windowAttributes)
    {
        Brand = brand;
        Height = height;
        Width = width;

        _windowAttributes = windowAttributes;
    }

    public string Brand { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<IWindowAttribute> GetWindowAttributes() => _windowAttributes;
}

A window attribute could be what ever you need it to be. The common IWindowAttribute might have a basic property common to all  or no properties if only used for abstraction.
public interface IWindowAttribute
{
    string Description { get; }
}

You then can add window attribute definitions as needed going forward.
Starting with the solar resistant attribute, either with unique properties or none if only used for abstraction.
public interface ISolarResistanceWindowAttribute : IWindowAttribute
{
    int ResistanceLevel { get; }
}

public class SolarResistanceWindowAttribute : ISolarResistanceWindowAttribute
{
    public string Description => "This window is solar resistant.";
    public int ResistanceLevel { get; set; }
}

The House class wouldn't have to change at this stage and if you want to add more attributes in the future you can them easily with more attribute definitions:
public interface IInsulationWindowAttribute : IWindowAttribute
{
    int InsulationLevel { get; }
}
    
public class InsulationWindowAttribute : IInsulationWindowAttribute
{
    public string Description => "This window is insulated.";
    public int InsulationLevel { get; set; }
}

Example usage in a small console test app might look like this:
IEnumerable<IWindowAttribute> windowAttributes = new List<IWindowAttribute>
{
    new SolarResistanceWindowAttribute
    {
        ResistanceLevel = 4
    },
    new InsulationWindowAttribute
    {
        InsulationLevel = 45
    }
};

IEnumerable<Window> windows = new List<Window>
{
    new Window("brand-A", 32,144, windowAttributes)
};

var myHouse = new House(windows);

foreach (var window in myHouse.Windows)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Window is a {window.Brand} window, with a height of {window.Height} and a width of {window.Width}");

    foreach (var windowAttribute in window.GetWindowAttributes())
    {
        switch (windowAttribute)
        {
            case ISolarResistanceWindowAttribute solarResistanceAttribute:
                Console.WriteLine($"Window is solar resistant with a resistance level of {solarResistanceAttribute.ResistanceLevel}");
                break;
            case IInsulationWindowAttribute insulationAttribute:
                Console.WriteLine($"Window is insulated with a insulation level of {insulationAttribute.InsulationLevel}");
                break;
        }
    }
}

This could open the project up for more abstraction when needed in the future, such as an IWindowProcessor injected into the House or similar. The processor could contain logic for different operations required for different attributes etc...
